# Is it possible to register all depenencies and only dependecies of a given class with Castle Windsor installer?

Tags: c#, castle-windsor

Consider the following set of classes:

```
public interface IService { }
public interface IDep1 { }
public interface IDep2 { }
public interface IDep3 { }

public class Dep1 : IDep1 { }
public class Dep2 : IDep2 { }
public class Dep3 : IDep3 { } // this one is not used

public class Service1 : IService
{
    public Service1(IDep1 dep1) { }
}
public class Service2 : IService
{
    public Service2(IDep1 dep1, IDep2 dep2) { }
}
```

I am using the following Castle Windsor installer to register all classes which inherit from **IService**:

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
  .BasedOn(typeof(IService))
  .WithServiceSelf()
  .WithServiceBase()
  .LifestyleTransient());
```

How can I write an installer which will register all classes, that are dependencies of already registered classes, but nothing more. In other words: How can I write a generic installer, which will register **IDep1** and **IDep2**, but not **IDep3** (because **IDep3** is not used by any **IService**?

Comment: Why would you keep IDep3 in your codebase if it's not being used?

Comment: Why does it matter if a class is registered but not used?

Comment: Because Dep3 is used elsewhere and I do not want it to be in the container.

Comment: My actual code is more complex and I didn't want to include the whole case here for simplicity.

Comment: Detecting code usage is very complex and usually deferred to static code analysis tools.

Answer (score 1):

You can try filtering the types with the `.Where`.

```
container.Register(Classes.FromThisAssembly()
  .BasedOn(typeof(IService))
  .WithServiceSelf()
  .WithServiceBase()
  .Where(type => !(type is IDep3))
  .LifestyleTransient());
```

[See documentation](https://github.com/castleproject/Windsor/blob/master/docs/registering-components-by-conventions.md#additional-filtering-and-configuration)

**But** it feels to me that doing so "smells" - Maybe have another interface that `IDep1` and `IDep2` will inherit from whereas `IDep3` won't, and do the registration by that interface

Comment: Agreed, however I believe the OP wishes to conditionally register types based on whether they are actually used by any implementation of IService.

Comment: Ya I also thought so but Castle doesn't really work that way... so decided just to give this option + my concerns

Comment: I definitely do not want to manually exclude IDep3. I rather want to visit a constructor, walk through all arguments and register those types and repeat recursively. My question is: do I have to do that manually or is there some tricky way to tell Castle to do that for me?

Comment: Castle actually knows what dependencies are needed. (IDiagnosticsHost)container.Kernel.GetSubSystem(SubSystemConstants.DiagnosticsKey).GetDiagnostic<IAllComponentsDiagnostic>().Inspect().ToList() gives you a ton of information

Comment: Sorry then I don't know a way that is there already. As you say then it is possible to get all these dependencies and then see what registrations aren't in any dependencies and remove them. I would still prefer looking again into the design and improve it or as stuard commented - just leave it there